# Error en agregar insignia a los productos PHP

Tags: php

Estoy deseando mostrar la insignia `nuevo`, para ello estaba probando el siguiente código pero me muestra siempre que es nuevo:

El código que estoy empleando:

```
function NewProduct(){
    
    $DateProduct = '2010-01-10 00:00:00';
    $days = 5;
    $offset = $days*60*60*24;

    if ($DateProduct < date('U') - $offset ) {
        echo '<span class="new-product">NEW</span>';
    }
}

NewProduct();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay un par de problemas con la lógica:

- No puedes comparar una cadena contra un [timestamp](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiempo_Unix)
- La comparación debe ser si la fecha del producto tiene menos de 5 días respecto a la fecha actual, es decir `fecha_de_producto` >= fecha_actual - 5 días

Lo primero que hay que hacer es convertir la fecha del producto en timestamp con [`strtotime()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.strtotime.php), después, restar 5 días de la fecha actual y realizar la comparación.

```
function NewProduct($fecha){
    $DateProduct = strtotime($fecha);
    $hoyMenos5 = strtotime("- 5 days");
    if ($DateProduct >= $hoyMenos5) {
        echo '<span class="new-product">NEW</span>';
    }
}

NewProduct('2020-09-25 00:00:00'); // NEW
NewProduct('2020-09-21 00:00:00'); // Nada
```